# Pass top-level function as callable to map

Tags: ruby, eval, first-class-functions

To be clear, I recognize that `eval` is evil, this is not for production code. That said, I'm trying to figure out if I can, for golfing purposes, shorten:

```
$*.map{eval _1}
```

any further, in much the same way that:

```
$*.map{|x|x.to_i}
# and
$*.map{_1.to_i}
```

can shorten to:

```
$*.map(&:to_i)
```

Python's first class functions make this easy; a listcomp like:

```
[eval(x)for x in sys.argv[1:]]
```

can shorten to:

```
[*map(eval,sys.argv[1:])]
```

because `eval` is a first-class function, and without parentheses it isn't called. But I've tried everything I can think of to suppress `eval` trying to run before being passed, e.g. `$*.map(&eval)`, `$*.map(:eval)`, and variations thereof, and it never works (because it calls `eval` with no arguments, or passes something that does not act as the `eval` function).

It's possible this can't be golfed, but I'm curious if there is any way, to get a *direct* reference to `eval` (not create some new custom `Proc` or `lambda` or the like that happens to invoke it internally) that can be passed around as an argument?

(To be clear, this isn't an actual code golf challenge, so I believe it remains on-topic for StackOverflow; I happen to want to do this for golf, but being able to convert top-level functions to first-class objects to pass them around is useful in some cases outside of golfing)

Comment: You could eval it the other way round via `eval"[#{$**?,}]"` but it's even longer.

Comment: @Stefan: That is actually something that has helped at times (due to precedence issues in some cases, I can avoid parentheses by `eval`ing the whole thing, where `eval`ing a subcomponent would require additional call parens and/or a space), but yeah, standing alone, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`eval` is a method in `Kernel`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) like most of the other things in Ruby that are "methods that pretend to be functions" so you can use [`Object#method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#method-i-method) to get a reference to it. Then use `&` to to convert that `Method` to a `Proc`:

```
$*.map(&method(:eval))
```

So `method(:eval)` is your "direct reference" to `eval`. But you still have to call `#to_proc` to get something that `#map` will be happy with.

Maybe not really great for golf due to the length of `method` but I can't think of anything else.